Discontinuity of $Log(z)$ at keyhole contour
I don't understand why we need to add a factor of $2\pi i$ if we go along the keyhole contour.
Suppose first we move along the unit circle and start at the point $z= 1+ 0i$, then
$$\log(z) = \ln(|z|) + i\cdot \arg(z) = 0,$$
where $\log(z)$ is the main branch of the complex logarithm.
And if we move along the unit circle (e.g. by analytic continuation of $\frac{1}{z}$) we increase the arg so when we arrive at $z=1+0i$ again we have
$$\widehat{\log(z)} = \ln(|z|) + i\cdot(\arg(z) + 2\pi) = 2\pi i,$$
where $\widehat{\log(z)} = \log(z) + 2\pi i$ is a different branch since we went over the cut. I totally understand this behaviour.
In the case of the keyhole contour

I do not understand why we have a jump here. Suppose we fix the point $z= r+ \frac{i}{r}$ (of the image) we then go along the curve. At every point of the curve the branch $\log(z): \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty) \to \mathbb {C}$ is defined on this curve and continous in particular. So in the case of residue calculus why do we define the $\log$ on the straight line below zero as another branch as the $\log$ on top?

They are not different branches, you are considering one branch of the logarithm on $\mathbb C\setminus[0,\infty)\to\mathbb C$. What is happening is that as $z$ approaches the line $(0,\infty)$ from below (as in the figure), say $z\to x\in(0,\infty)$ from below, its argument approaches $2\pi$, and so you get that $\log(z)=\ln(\lvert z\rvert)+i\operatorname{arg}(z)\to\ln(x)+2\pi i$. In other terms the next branch gives the local analytic continuation across the line $(0,\infty)$, but the logarithm can't be globally extended

Ok, I think I understand. So the Integral $- \int_{-i/r}^{r-i/r} \log(z) dz \to - \int_0^\infty (\ln(z) + 2\pi i) dz$ for $r\to\infty$ whereas $\int_{i/r}^{r+i/r} \log(z) dz \to \int_0^\infty \ln (z)dz$ for $r\to\infty$?
